# Integrating RubyMine with GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, rubymine, github-for-windows

I am *just* learning Ruby and Rails, and am using RubyMine on Windows as my IDE.  GitHub has just released [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/). I installed it, and it seems like a nice interface.  However, it does not seem to have installed anything like a git.exe for RubyMine to pick up and work with.  So RubyMine whines that it can't find git, and git (in the form of  GitHub for Windows) sits there blithely ignoring RubyMine.

Naturally, I've looked for information on the GitHub site - nothing. Am I going to have to install the "old" git client for RubyMine to use?

Comment: There's nothing "old" about the Git command line client.

Answer (score 13):

**GitHub** distribution is bundled with **PortableGit** which is unpacked into `AppData\Local\GitHub` and you can use this **git** client in RubyMine.

Full path to the **git** executable provided by **GitHub** installation that can be used in RubyMine on my system is:

```
c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_0812189c12ccff4584523d6efce294a33dd2332a\bin\git.exe
```

Note that it's probably some random hash in the path so it may be different on your system.

If you don't want to dig for this executable, just install and use [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), there should be no difference, in fact the version currently reported by **GitHub PortableGit** is:

`git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1` vs `git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1` of the latest **msysgit** available at the moment of writing this answer. So the "old" command line client is newer than the "new" GitHub provided client, at least now.