# PhpStorm and Github for Windows

Tags: git, phpstorm, github-for-windows

PhpStorm integration with Git asks me for `git.exe` path, however "github for windows" seems like it doesn't create any git.exe file. So is it a way to config phpstorm so it use "github for windows" for working with github?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating RubyMine with GitHub for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497506/integrating-rubymine-with-github-for-windows)

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes sir, that solves this question too. Thanks!

Comment: You can also change your PhpStorm terminal to use Git Bash by going into Settings > Terminal > Shell path and setting it to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`

Comment: Mine only worked using this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` (WebStorm 10)

Answer (score 20):

I set it up using [Git Bash](http://git-scm.com/downloads), once installed in PhpStorm go to:

> settings > version control > Git

And point to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

Or where ever you installed Git Bash

Answer (score 6):

To configure Git with PhpStorm on Windows 7 use the following path :

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

( Used with Git version is 2.7.1.0 )

Answer (score 1):

Github for Windows uses a version of PortableGit located in the AppData\Local\Github folder.

Very similar to the RubyMine Issue above:
[Integrating RubyMine with GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497506/integrating-rubymine-with-github-for-windows)