# I can't find my git.exe file in my Github folder

Tags: github-for-windows

I downloaded Github for windows and installed it on my computer, which runs windows 7. I tried to open a project with Android Studio but it says "Can't start Git: git.exe" and "IDE error".

When I click "Fix it" it shows:

> "Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system
>   cannot find the file specified".

So I googled and I tried to find git.exe file in my Github folder.
In my Github folder there is two folders: one is a project shared by my friend and the other one is "Git1".
In Git1 foler, there are only two files: ".gitattributes" and ".gitignore"
I can't find "git.exe" file even with the search bar of windows.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/6309

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/37256917/1616003

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The git.exe from Github for windows is located in a path like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<numbersandletters>\bin\git.exe`[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127984/1928529) You have to replace `<username>` and `<numbersandletters>` to the actual situation on your system.

In Android Studio you can specify the path to the Git executable at `File->Settings...->Version Control->Git->Path to Git executable`. Here you have to include the actual executable name. As an example, in my case the actual path is: `C:\Users\dennis\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_69703d1db91577f4c666e767a6ca5ec50a48d243\bin\git.exe`

**Edit:** Last git update has put the git.exe file in cmd\ folder instead of bin\ . so now the actual path will be as suggested in the comment below by al3xAndr3w.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<numbersandletters>\cmd\git.exe
```

Comment: last windows git update moved the exe to the cmd folder instead of the bin, so you can use that for IDEs such as webstorm and other.. BUT!: if you want to have git and ssh and ls and other linux commands in win powershell or cmd add to the windows PATH folder ..../PortableGit..4kj3h43k4..../mingw32/bin/

Comment: @al3xAndr3w Nice find! Feel free to create your own answer for this as it contains some new elements and I've gotten far more points with this post than my simple answer deserves. If you don't I will probably edit this information into this answer for better visibility in a few days.

Comment: For `Git for Windows` users (not `GitHub for Windows`) git.exe path is probably already in `PATH` variable and you can find the path by `where git.exe` on git-cmd which is by default "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"

Comment: Gone. no more git.exe at that location

Answer (score 20):

run github that you downloaded, click tools and options symbol(top right), click about github for windows and then open the debug log. under DIAGNOSTICS look for Git Executable Exists:

Comment: And if it doesn't exist?

Comment: If you don't see it, do a crtl + f (search on the .txt file) for the key words, "4|StartupLogging| Git Executable Exists:" and the path following that text should show it. Otherwise, I'd suggest upgrading to the latest github client.

Answer (score 16):

I found git here

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.5.8\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe
```

You have to write file name (git.exe) in the end of path otherwise it will give an error=5[image]

---

Or you can check here also.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The last update for "windows git" did move the git.exe file from the /bin folder to the /cmd folder. So, to use git with IDEs such as webStorm or Android Studio you can use the path :

> C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<..numbers..>\cmd\git.exe

But if you want to have linux-like commands such as **git**, **ssh**, **ls**, **cp** under windows powerShell or cmd add to your windows PATH variables :

> C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<...numbers...>\usr\bin

change <user> and <...numbers...> to your values and reboot!

Also, you will have to update this everytime git updates since it might change the portable folder name. If folder structure changes I will update this post.

Thx @dennisschagt for the comment above! ;)

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue and was not able to find it out where git.exe is located. After spending so much time I fount that in my windows 8, it is located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin

And for command line :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

Hope this helps someone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 2.10.1, here is the path -

C:\Users\usersam\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 4):

1) Install Git for Windows from here: http://git-scm.com/download/win

2) **Note:** During installation, Make sure ***"Use Git and optional Unix tools from the windows command prompt"*** is selected 
[image]

3) restart the Android Studio and try again

4) Go to File-> New -> Project from version control -> Git

Answer (score 3):

I found my `git.exe` here

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

while installing `git`, it asks for the location. copy it and use it.

Answer (score 2):

The path for the latest version of Git is changed, In my laptop, I found it in

> C:\Users\Anum Sheraz\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe

This resolved my issue of path. Hope that helps to someone :)