# Publishing a Project on GitHub

Tags: github, version-control, phpstorm

I want to use this way to upload my project to GitHub ([Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/publishing-a-project-on-github.html)):

> To publish you project sources on GitHub
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose VCS | Import into Version Control | Share
>      Project on GitHub .
>
>    - If you have registered login and password,
>        PhpStorm establishes connection with GitHub using these credentials.
>    - If you have not registered your GitHub credentials in PhpStorm, the
>        Login to GitGub dialog box. Specify your GitHub login and password or
>        create an account there.
> 2. Upon establishing connection, the Share
>      Project on GitHub dialog box opens. Specify the name of the repository
>      to store your project sources in. By default, PhpStorm suggests the
>      name of the current project. Provide a brief description of the
>      project functionality. Click the Share button. PhpStorm initiates
>      creation of the new repository on the GitHub and uploads the project
>      sources to it.

First step works, added my GitHub login data, test the connection and it works.
Now upon step 2, after clicking the Share Project on GitHub link this error shows up:

> - Error Running Git.
>
> Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system can not find the file specified

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS is seemingly Windows but what version?

This might be what you need tough: [I can't find my git.exe file in my Github folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077449/i-cant-find-my-git-exe-file-in-my-github-folder)

Comment: Windows 8.1, and as far as I know Git/GitHub isn't needed to be downloaded. On my old laptop I had before I didn't had any of the Git programs installed and this method worked