# Git command not recognized; where is it located?

Tags: git, github, windows-8

I'm trying to learn Github and following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fKg7e37bQE). I keep getting `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` in cmd. I tried adding it to the PATH environment variable, but have no clue where Git.exe is located, or even if the install was succesfull. I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit and in control panel there is GitHub by GitHub inc. In `C:\Program Files\Git` there is one file called `mtab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the path to git.exe in Windows:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_\bin\git.exe

for more detail click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

Comment: oops I didn't see that before posting

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to reference the embedded `git.exe` packaged with [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) ([that path is quite complex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26088380/6309)), simply uncompress the [latest git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) which is [`PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want.

Then add to your `%PATH%`:

```
C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit\bin
```