# lntelliJ IDEA EAP 12 and Bitbucket ( Git or Mercurial )

Tags: git, mercurial, intellij-idea, dvcs, bitbucket

My Sytem setup is

1. Windows 7 64-bit
2. IntelliJ IDEA EAP 12 version 122.639
3. Java 1.6
4. I am a non Admin user.

I have an android project which I want to keep under version control on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org). I have tried to use the builtin VCS in IntelliJ IDEA to create git/mercurial but for both of them I get the error about **hg.exe** / **git.cmd** not found.

FYI, I have to checkout stuff from GitHub and it worked without problems. I also have the BitBucket plugin installed.

**How do I use inbuilt VCS in IntelliJ IDEA to create git/Mercurial repo for my local projects and save them on my Bitbucket account.**

**EDIT**
@crazycoder

I have installed msysgit as you advised and here is the git path config screen as requested by you.
[image: Git Path Config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't bundle Git/Mercurial version control systems, it provides the integration, but the tools need to be installed separately.

See also the related questions:

- [Integrating RubyMine with GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11497506/104891)
- [Where is git.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11928561/104891)

Comment: Installing either of one of Git or msysGit should work.. True?

Comment: Although, I have been been able to get past the initial problem by isntalling msysGit and saving the path. I commited/uploaded the project on bitbucket but now when I open thsi project  aroung 10-12 DOS command windows open up, same thing happens even if I change a single character in source file. Furthermore, I can't seem to push the changes to bitbucket. Can you please give me some intructions to properly setup and update (push) my project.

Comment: Edit your question with the screenshot of the git path configuration.

Comment: You are using incorrect file, specify the path to `git.exe`. On my system (and I believe it's the default) the path is: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe`.

Comment: Unfortunately Thye only instance of Git.exe I have found on my system is at c:\msysgit\msysgit\git\git.exe

Answer (score 1):

Not sure. But I would seriously consider installing MSysGit and using the command line instead. You get history tracking which is as-you-type searchable with ctrl-R, allowing you to see what you did a couple of days ago to make that rebase work, etc. Other benefits are tab-completion for branch and path, command piping and easier assistance with problems as it is pure git and you'll get way more help with it than you will with intelliJ's git implementation/integration.